# Meeting 508 Accessibility requirements for complex data tables

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility

I'm using a [extension for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=accessibility%20evaluation) to check for 508 compliance issues.

I'm getting the following two errors which I have been unable to resolve on each report:

> Fail: Data tables must use th elements to indicate header cells for the first cell in all the columns or rows.
>
> Fail: For complex data tables, the td elements must have headers attributes that point to associated th header ids.

The addon highlights the following table cell for both errors but I can't find anything wrong with it:

```
<table cellpadding="5" width="100%" style ="text-align:right" class ="ecoRow" summary="Budget History" title="Budget History">

<tr> <th id="date_range" colspan="7" style="text-align:center;">From #params.start_date# To #params.end_date#</th></tr>
```

What to do?

Comment: You probably need to show us a bit more of the table.

Comment: You definitely need to show us the _entire_ table.

Comment: Read this article. It has the answers that you are looking for http://www.usability.com.au/resources/tables.cfm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this firefox extension and ran into this same issue today.
It appears that the tool wants to see some text inside the  element.

Other dev on the team replaced plain text header labels with buttons and anchors. anchors were passing with the tool, but buttons weren't. We already had the scope defined and all the closing tags (I checked).

Results may differ, but this fixed our issue.
Note that the passing lines have actual text between tags.

- Fail: `<th><input type="button" text="blah"></input></th>`
- Fail: `<th><img url="blah.jpg"></img></th>`
- Pass: `<th><a href="www.blah.com">blah</a></th>`
- Pass: `<th><span>blah</span></th>`
- Pass: `<th>blah</th>`

Answer (score 1):

I see several things about the table that can be improved (inline styles, lack of `<tbody>`, etc), but header identification is not one of them. Then again, I can't see the entire table. But it looks like the plugin evidently doesn't understand a colspan. Try adding a `scope="col"` to the header.

For an alternative plugin, try the WAVE toolbar: http://wave.webaim.org/toolbar

**UPDATE**: Now that I see the table via the pastbin link in the comment, I see some serious problems. First and foremost, there's no closing table tag. You have some rows wider than others. You have an empty row that has has been inserted for display purposes. Don't do that, use CSS.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rNzyJA3b

I got rid of the first error by not leaving the first cell blank. still getting the second error though for the same cell. 

>Fail: For complex data tables, the td elements must have headers attributes that point to associated th header ids.

Comment: First cell blank? What you've got and what you're showing us are two different things.